# Show validations from api response angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api

this is the response which i am getting form api response

```
{"status":9,"message":{"username":"Please Enter Username !","password":"Please Enter Password !"}}
```

and i am want to show these errors like this

[image]

any one can help me into this please !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can go with something like this for starters: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-form-validation-rvri78

The stackblitz has form control, but it seems to me you don't use it since you're calling API to handle the case if fields are empty?

But why would you call API if fields are empty? You should just call it if form is valid, and let API return some error if the user is not existing or wrong combination of username/password etc.

Comment: thanks for this, it is really good method I'm also tried it but  I want to show all validation by loop
  -> My Response
  {"status":9,"message":{"username":"Please Enter Username !","password":"Please Enter Password !"}}
 ->Code
   `this.apiSerivce.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe((response) => {
      if(response['status'] == 1) {
        //Show Success Response
      } else if(response['status'] == 9) {
        //Show Validation by loop
      } else {
        //Show Other Response
      }
    })`

Comment: What do you mean by 'show validation by loop'? Are you going to have more than those 2 fields? More possible error messages inside status 9?

Comment: yes, More possible error messages inside status 9

Comment: So, you have username and password fields, and messages can be of any number in API response? So in status.messages.username are the messages expected to come as array if there's more than 1? Like: "messages": { "username": [ "First error", "Second error", "Third error"], "password": [...]}?

Comment: for this type of response {'status': 9, 'messages': {'name':'error', 'email':'error', 'mobile_no':'error', 'profile':'error'}} show validation by loop in all fields

Comment: So do you use form control? Do you have 4 input fields (name, email, mobile_no, profile) and they can each get just one error message? Trying to figure out exactly what do you need to achieve :)

Comment: Yes there are 4 or more inputs and each one have one error as given format & all input error show by loop from ts to html